# Make comment balloons multiple colors for same author

Tags: microsoft-word, comments

I'd like to know if it's possible to create, for example, 10 notes, and color 2 of them blue, 3 yellow and 5 green in Microsoft Word.

It's red for me now, but I would like to have different colors for different issues.

I've found the option to change the color, but that changes all of them, not just the selected comment.

Is this possible at all? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is as much a request for clarification as an answer. There are at least two options and I am not sure why one or other of these is not suitable:

1. If you want insertions/deletions etc to have different colours go to Review > Tracking - Track Changes and Change Tracking Options, the options are many:

   [image: SU607054 example]
2. Down one in the menu and Change User Name (and back again afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.  However, you can either (1) use different font colors for different types of comments in the comment text itself or (2) use different highlight colors for different types of comments in the comment text itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the User Name and associated the User Name to the issue. The only setback is either identifying all issues at the same time under the user name before changing or constantly changing the user name for new comments relating to the specific issue.